# Siphon for testing new recipes: 250ml or 500ml?

Tags: equipment

I already own two 1 litre ISI siphons but they are too big when I'm developing a new mousse or recipe in general.
I don't have a restaurant, I just do this in my free time, and I was considering buying a small siphon for testing new recipes.
Would you recommend the 250ml or the 500ml? I tend to think that the smallest one would be the best suit, but I'm worried that it's very small.

Ideas?

Comment: I wonder if you could put something solid, food-safe and insoluble (like silicone used for making molds, or a small sealed jar of water) inside your existing canister to let you work effectively with smaller quantities without the expense of getting another siphon.

Comment: It's unclear what the issue really is here. You're the only one who knows whether the kinds of things you're trying to make will fit in 250mL. If there's something specific you want to find out, please edit and flag this to be reopened.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you want to make 500ml, nothing stops you from using the 250ml one twice, right?

250ml is sufficient to judge a recipe - of course, if you do test runs with your family of 6, 250ml might be a bad choice.